# Custom TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to pass data to another controller and then show in the custom table view.How can I connect model in SearchViewController with model in SearchViewControllerTableView

// Data comes another controller

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let navController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController

    if  let controller : SearchViewController = navController.topViewController as? SearchViewController {

        if  segue.identifier == "segue"{

            controller.model = movies    // pass data to Another Controller

        }
    }
}

class SearchViewController: UIViewController{


    var model = [Movie] ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}

class SearchViewControllerTableView: UITableView,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    var model = [Movie]()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1  // should be model.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = self.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mycell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        /* Should be  myCell.movieTitle.text = model[indexPath.row].title

         urlToImage((string: model[indexPath.row].thumbnail!)) { (image) in

         myCell.movieImage.image = image

         }
         return myCell  */
    }
}
```

Comment: simply create a outlet of SearchViewControllerTableView in SearchViewController and then assign the model value to SearchViewControllerTableView model for e.g outletproperty.model = model

Comment: Is your segue connected with `TableViewCell`?

Comment: sure. Just, I don't know how to do passing model can use in the custom table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a outlet of SearchViewControllerTableView in SearchViewController and assign data to SearchViewControllerTableView property model

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: SearchViewControllerTableView!
    var model = [Movie] ()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  // assign data to SearchViewControllerTableView model
      tableView.model = self.model

 }
```

}